# Clearinterval() for setinterval()

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I clearInterval() for all setInterval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958433/how-can-i-clearinterval-for-all-setinterval)

I called setInterval in my page, and I don't have access to the original variable that setInterval was stored in, but I want to clear it from my page.

so how can i clear all timers present on a page?

Comment: Might I be so bold as to suggest something as radical as writing better code?

Comment: @j08691 In fact it's a frequently asked question, with always the same answer : override setInterval to register the handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear ALL the intervals!

```
// This could take a while.
for (var i=0; i<2147483647; i++) clearInterval(i);
```

You could probably tone down that max value of `i` and still catch 'em all. The above code finished in my browser after only 12008757 milliseconds. That's 3.3 hours, or ~179 `clearInterval()`s per millisecond.

Comment: You just made me kill my browser :)

Comment: haha +1 for this being awesome

Comment: `for(;;){}` is equivalent. No more interval running.

Comment: @dystroy except that `for (var i=0; i<2147483647; i++)` _will_ eventually terminate.

Comment: @MattBall Oh, that's the perfect solution then. Thanks for the update, I'm glad I didn't wait :)   I'm curious of the implementation of intervals, it's possible to do so many things in 1/179 seconds...