# How does Facebook manage to kill javascript when going to a new page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, settimeout, setinterval

Try this.

Type this code into your browser console on the homepage of Facebook (your Facebook feed):

```
setInterval(function(){console.log('blah')}, 100)
```

Then navigate to the "Messages" or "Events" section of the website. Notice that the whole page is not reloaded and the new html content is inserted dynamically with javascript. However, somehow Facebook cancels the `setInterval`. This also happens with `setTimeout`.

How is this happening?

Comment: perhaps they are clearing all intervals on the window object when you actively open an item such as messages to avoid timers reloading fresh content?

Comment: @pst http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958433/how-can-i-clearinterval-for-all-setinterval second answer.

Comment: @pst and is that what they're doing?

Comment: ooooh that is what they are doing! Typing `setTimeout` on Facebook shows their own function.

Comment: seems they're clearing timeouts `onLeave` what that means in facebook context and their minfied js code, who knows.

Comment: @user730569 If the approach is determined through inspection, remember to self-answer for future reference.

Comment: @pst I figured f0x would want to answer b/c he really figured it out.

Comment: Nah don't stress; mine was just a guess, you found that they're rolling their own timeout function so go ahead ;p

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that Facebook is overriding the native `setTimeout` and `setInterval` functions with their own. You can see this by typing `setTimeout` into your browser console and it will return a function different from the typical `native code` function. Facebook therefore has access to all `setTimeouts` on the page, even ones by third party code, and can therefore clear them all when you access a new page (or whenever they want, really).