# Finding Leftover setTimeouts and setIntervals

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to see currently running timeouts and/or intervals created with setTimeout or setInterval?

Since each one returns an ID, is there a way to view the current ones in a developer console? This would help me find "leaks" in my application.

The only way I can think to do this now is to create a wrapper for my setInterval/setTimeout calls. Or to override the built in ones (ie `window.setTimeout=function()`) in window and then have an object map keep track.

Comment: I think a better approach to find "leaks" caused by setTimeout/Interval would be showing them in a separate section in JS heap snapshots rather than providing list of them in the developer console.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958433/how-can-i-clearinterval-for-all-setinterval),

```
for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++){
   window.clearInterval(i);
   window.clearTimeout(i);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @K2xL: Yeah, based on the link given here, may be you could try to override the setTimeout/setInterval and then to trigger an error with a line # `(new Error).lineNumber` if it runs too long

Answer (score 1):

This code i just wrote for you (fun exercise) overrides the `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` functions and creates ones which keep track of which timeouts are available in a global variable called `timeouts`. Try it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KqZmb/

```
(function() {
  window.timeouts = [];
  var _setTimeout = window.setTimeout;
  window.setTimeout = function() { 
    var id = _setTimeout.apply( this, arguments );
    timeouts.push( id );
    _setTimeout( function() {
        timeouts.splice( timeouts.indexOf( id ), 1);
      }, arguments[1] );
     return id;
  };
  var _clearTimeout = window.clearTimeout;
  window.clearTimeout = function( id ) { 
    _clearTimeout( id );
    timeouts.splice( timeouts.indexOf( id ), 1);
  };
})();
```

You can adapt it easily for `setInterval` and `clearInterval`.

What I want to say though is that you probably need to keep track of your timeouts in order to avoid weird behavior in your application...